# Missing includes during compilation (Cocos2d-x 3.1 + XCode 5.1.1)

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

It appear that I can't solve this trivial looking problem...

I downloaded Libcocos2d-x, ran the dependancies script:

```
$> ./download-deps.py
```

who filled the "external/" folder with all the third party headers.

Then I generated a project using:

```
$> ./cocos new -p "xx.xx.xx" -l cpp -d "xx/xx/xx"
```

This worked fine.

But when I try to compile this new born project, the only thing I get are includes errors.
I tried to fix them manually, but nothing to do, even when "curl.h" get included, he keep asking for "curl/curl.h" and vice versa.
And curl is just the start of it, it looks like all the .h of the cocos project are missing:

```
/Users/xx/Desktop/Dev/aa/cocos2d/extensions/assets-manager/AssetsManager.cpp:27:10: 'curl/curl.h' file not found
/Users/xx/Desktop/Dev/aa/cocos2d/cocos/platform/CCSAXParser.cpp:30:10: 'tinyxml2.h' file not found
etc...
```

If anyone has any clue about this I'm listening.

Comment: platform you're trying to compile for?  Is it the bare Hello World project or did you change anything?  Did you get any errors in the console when you ran setup.py?  download-deps.py?

Comment: @Javy Didn't tried setup.py, I'm at work but I'll do it tonight and let you know. I'm trying to compile for IOS, and yes this is the bare example project.

Comment: @Javy what does setup.py is used for?

Comment: @Mayer - `setup.py` is used to set a few environment variables for the cocos command line tool and also android development. You do need to run it. Also make sure to `source ~/.bash_profile` after. Running `download-deps is only required if you downloaded from GitHUB. For OS X Please see: `http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_run_cpp-tests_on_iOS`

Comment: Ok, thanks for those infos @GameDeveloper. I do downloaded it from GitHub.
I'll try to run setup.py, but I think I'll just copy-pasta those variable because I'm running zsh. Let me check all that

Comment: This doesn't fix anything, this script just give make a bind to cocos to be accessible from anywhere.
That doesn't fixed my problem, neither does the link I already knew :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this tutorial here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXqgSNUf9Cc&list=PLRtjMdoYXLf4od_bOKN3WjAPr7snPXzoe

Make sure to download the new 3.1.1 hotfix so you are on the latest version.

Don't skip anything you've already done.  Redo every step to insure nothing is wrong.

Make sure you run setup.py then download-deps, then create a new project in a different directory.  You may have made some changes that caused problems.

Also, log any install errors and post them here.

Comment: Roger, your answer made me doubt about something I did and maybe shouldn't have done. Let me try this first then I redo everything

Comment: Ok looks like it is working. The problem must have been that I moved the created project folder to another location.
I don't get it because I manually corrected the headers/lib etc paths. Must have been a mistake. Anyway thanks you opened my closed eyes over this, and your solution can be accepted since it's the right method to do with everything.

Comment: Note that if you clone cocos2dx from github, this error will occur. So you need to execute download-deps.py (can be found in your proj/cocos2d/ folder.